# How to completely uninstall outlook 2007&2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

The issue arises when outlook upgraded to 2010. After it upgraded to 2010,the outlook is not connected to server,not able to receive/send mails. Strange thing is not able to view the Mail icon in control panel. Then uninstalled the 2010,and reinstalled 2007 setup able to view the Mail icon in control panel. Again created the new profile then when try to open the outlook showing the error as "**cannot open the default email folders**"

Could you please help me to solve the issue by completely uninstall the outlook .I need to start freshly outlook

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the mail applet where it sometimes opens an old Outlook profile. Open regedit and browse to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles and delete any profiles that should not be there. Then restart Outlook.